# Авторизация через cURL не работает - PHP

Tags: php, php-curl

Пишу скрипт, авторизация для сайта *freelance.ru* не срабатывает,на *авито* и *ливеинтернет* все успешно проходит. Подскажите, где кроется ошибка, в каком направлении копать?

При ручной авторизации заголовки следующие:

```
form data:

login:**********

passwd:********

submit: (unable to decode value)

auth:auth

return_url:/login/

======

Request Headers:

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate

Accept-Language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Cache-Control:max-age=0

Connection:keep-alive

Content-Length:90

Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Cookie:user_id=1ej5m1c1wXxC45JYGxnEAg==; _ym_uid=1463140732863148124; _ym_isad=1; checkIP=false; _ym_visorc_57896=w

Host:freelance.ru

Origin:freelance.ru

Referer:freelance.ru/login/

Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
```

---

```
<?php

    header("content-type: text/html;charset=windows-1251");

    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);


    $url = "https://freelance.ru/login/";


    //замеряем время начала работы скрипта
    $st_time =  microtime(true);

    function get_result($url){

        $ch = curl_init();
        $headers = [
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0',
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
            'Connection: keep-alive'
        ];

        $referer = "https://freelance.ru/";

        $post_fields = array(
            "login" => "****", // логин
            "passwd" => "****",  // пароль
             "submit" => "Вход",
            "auth" => "auth",
            "return_url" => "/login/"
        ); 


        $cookie = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie.txt";
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); // следовать за редиректами
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);// просто отключаем проверку сертификата
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); // использовать данные в post
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);

        $res = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_error($ch))
        {
        echo "\n\ncURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
        echo "\n\ncURL error:" . curl_errno($ch);
        //$flagerrcurl = true;
        }

        return $res;
    }
    echo get_result($url);
    $end_time   =   microtime(true);
    echo "<br><br>".($end_time - $st_time);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Авторизация с капчей. Которую вы не отправляете. Возможно при ручной авторизации капча не выскакивает из-за того что ваш IP адрес сайт посчитал доверенным. Предлагаю закрыть или удалить вопрос.